# Adding Images in windows forms display in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I'm building a simple windows form in Visual Studio.  I have to populate a multiline text box with details of different cars and scroll through them using a forward and back button.  Simple..... but I want to display a different picture with each entry.  How do I do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Show us some code!

Comment: You can use a combination of ListBox and PictureBox controls. ListBox has an event ListBoxt.SelectedIndexChanged which will allow you to set pictures accordingly via the PictureBox.Image property

Comment: Keep each car item seperate, like in a ListBox rather than gluing all the text together in a TB.  Otherwise, you'll spend pointless time parsing it back  out to find out which car is "current"

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm pretty new to this (2nd year computing Bsc). I'll try using a list box instead.